# Turtle Graphics stops responding once done

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to use the turtle module in python, as the title says, the graphics window crashes as soon as the graphic has finished drawing.  My code is:

```
import turtle

for x in range (0, 4):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
```

*I know, complex*

I have looked around online and found solutions saying use `done()` or `turtle.done()` or `exitonclick()` at the end, but none of those have worked.  I am new to Python so the answer is probably something blatantly obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an instance of a new turtle and

try to finish with `turtle.done()`

```
import turtle
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
for x in range (0, 4):
    my_turtle.forward(100)
    my_turtle.right(90)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: I've tried that already and it doesn't seem to work. It comes up with
    AttrubuteError: 'Turtle' object gas no attribute 'done'